# Check variable exists with Pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I really like the idea of making my policies in charge of making sure all variables are populated and valid, so we don't get any nil:nilClass errors or similar.

I thought it would be good to make sure a user has uploaded a file using a policy:

Here's my create action:

```
def create
    file = params[:file][:uploaded_file]
    authorize file
    # removed for brevity
end
```

And here's its policy:

```
class AssetPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    def initialize(current_user, record)
        @current_user = current_user
        @record = record
    end

    def create?
        @record != nil          
    end
end
```

However, I get the following unexpected errors:

When file is nil:

```
Pundit::NotDefinedError in Admin::Browser::AssetsController#create
unable to find policy NilClassPolicy for
```

When file is not nil:

```
Pundit::NotDefinedError in Admin::Browser::AssetsController#create
unable to find policy ArrayPolicy for [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000050a2af8]
```

So how should I check something exists with pundit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing this in my controller:

```
file = params[:file][:uploaded_file]
raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError if file == nil
```

It works fine, but I'd like this logic to be in my policy layer :/ At first I thought it might not make sense semantically, as this isn't an authorization thing, but it is when you think about it does make sense; if the user has not uploaded a file they are not authorized to access the create action.

Anyway, I want this logic in my policy layer. Open to all suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

In your config/initializers/pundit.rb file, you could add

```
rescue_from Pundit::NotDefinedError, with: :user_not_authorized
```

Answer (score 0):

The way pundit works is that is looks at the class of the object you are passing to it and then calls that policy.

According to the [pundit github](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) authorize will call something equivalent to this (assuming @asset is of the Asset class):

```
raise "not authorized" unless AssetPolicy.new(current_user, @asset).create?
```

So, in order to get around the problem, you could do this in your controller:

```
def create
  file = params[:file][:uploaded_file]
  raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError unless AssetPolicy.new(current_user, file).create?
  # removed for brevity
end
```